# Next JS: how do I update the data passed to a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a component that I would like to display fields based on the json that is fetched. I am new to JS/React/Next.js, and I can't figure out how to pass the json to the component after it fetched from my API.

I am successful in passing the data with my getInitialProps, but not when attempting to update the information. This is the function that works:

```js
Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/daily')
  const json = await res.json()
  return {data: json}
}
```

This is my function to update, which I can't get to work:

```js
const getArias = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/daily')
    const json = await res.json()
    return {data: json}  
  }
```

And here is the component that I would like to pass the information to is simple:

```
      <AriaItem ariaInfo={ariaInfo} />
```

I think it has something to do with how I set up the page, but I'm in a bit over my head with JS and can't quite figure it out. This is what the start of index.js looks like:

```js
const Home = ({data}) => {
  const [ariaInfo, setAriaInfo] = useState(data);
```

I don't think the component itself is causing issues, but just to show everything, here it is:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
const AriaItem = ({ariaInfo}) => {
    return (
        <div className= "block">
            <div className="p-4">
                <div className="border-solid border-4 border-gray-600">
                    {ariaInfo.Title}
                    <br></br>
                    {ariaInfo.Opera}
                    <br></br>
                    {ariaInfo.Composer}
                    <br></br>
                    {ariaInfo.Voice}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default AriaItem
```

Thank you for any help or guidance you may have. Again, to be clear, I am just looking to pass a fetched json to the AriaItem, in order to update the information it displays.

EDIT:
Here is the full Home code:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import AriaItem from '../components/AriaItem'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const Home = ({data}) => {
  const [ariaInfo, setAriaInfo] = useState(data);

  
  const getArias = async () => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/daily')
    const json = await res.json()
    return {data: json}  
  }

  return (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>Home</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </Head>
          <div className="w-full m-4">
          My Aria Result:
          <AriaItem ariaInfo={ariaInfo} />
        </div>   
  </div>
)}

Home.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/daily')
  const json = await res.json()
  return {data: json}
}
export default Home
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! can you share a little bit more code for Home component?

Comment: @artfulbeest Thank you! Yes, I just edited the original post to show the full home component at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put API calling logic in a useEffect. Make it run only once on load.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import AriaItem from '../components/AriaItem'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'

const getArias = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/daily')
  const json = await res.json()
  return {data: json}  
};

const Home = ({data}) => {
  const [ariaInfo, setAriaInfo] = useState(data);

  useEffect(() => {
    let {data} = getArias();
    setAriaInfo(data); // sets ariaInfo state
  } 
  , []);

  return (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>Home</title>
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </Head>
          <div className="w-full m-4">
          My Aria Result:
          <AriaItem ariaInfo={ariaInfo} />
        </div>   
  </div>
)}

export default Home
```

Note: I moved `getArias()` out of the component to just simplify readability.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful.